# Working with maps in Golang

Tags: sorting, dictionary, go

I am new to Go and doing a few exercises. One of them is to sort the numbers in an array by frequency, from most to least frequent.

```
Example: 
Input: [2, 2, 5, 7, 4, 4, 4, 7, 2]
Output: [2, 4, 7, 5]
```

Note that `[4, 2, 7, 5]` would also be correct, since 4 and 2 have the same frequency.

For this purpose I am converting the array into a **value value** map, which here would look like this: `[2:3][4:3][7:2][5:1]` (2 and 3 have freq. of 3, 7 has the freq of 2,... )

Afterwards I would like to simply loop through the map and output the **keys** ordered by **value**. For that I use the following code, which apparently does not work. Why?

```
count := 0
max := -1

// break loop, if map is empty
for i := 0; i < 1; i-- {
    if len(m) == 0 {
        break
    }

    max = -1

    // get key of biggest value
    for k, v := range m {
        if v > max {
            max = k
        }
    }
    // res (for result) is a slice of integers
    res[count] = max
    // remove key-value-pair from map
    delete(m, max)
    count++
}
return res
```

Please keep in mind that this is an exercise. I am very sure there are much better, build in ways to do this.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What are you expecting and what did you get? It's much easier if you create a standalone example that can also be run on https://play.golang.org/

Comment: @JimB I got [4 2 5 7] as a result 

here is a quick standalone version of the program: https://play.golang.org/p/GDKYAQbyUU8

Comment: That code is rather hard to understand, and I'm not sure what the intent is because of the nonsensical comparisons going on. The basic method you seem to be going for is to make a map of counts, make a slice of the unique values, then sort the unique values by their count. This could look like: https://play.golang.org/p/jepEyTuD9bW

Comment: @User12547645 I think the problem is that you're not keeping track of the max value, only of the max key and then comparing values against keys. Is this what you're after https://play.golang.org/p/VS2EMGUc2Kj?

Comment: @mkopriva Should I not get the max val by using m[maxKey]?

Comment: @JimB Thank you very much for the working solution. 

Why all this nonsense? I was just trying to do the sorting manually, by always selecting the key with the may value and adding it to the result slice

Comment: @User12547645 Your version wasn't comparing frequencies (values) to get the number (key) with the highest one. You were comparing keys to values. And that's just not correct.

Comment: for k, v := range m {
   if v > max {
    max = k
   }
  }

Would this not compare the values of the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'max' variable is meant to keep track of the maximum *frequency* seen so far. However when you do 'max = k' you're assigning a key.

You need to keep track of the maximum frequency and the key associated with that frequency in separate variables.

```
...
for k, v := range m {
    if v > maxFreq {
        maxFreq = v
        mostFrequentKey = k
    }
}
// res (for result) is a slice of integers
res[count] = mostFrequentKey
// remove key-value-pair from map
delete(m, mostFrequentKey)
count++
...
```

Comment: It's far far simpler than that.  The frequency of the most frequent key is equal to `m[max]`.  If you change the conditional inside the map loop from `if v > max` to `if v > m[max]`, it works precisely as expected.  https://play.golang.org/p/xam2BMjeOoK

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out @Kaedys. I musst have just missed that, when I did that exercise.

Answer (score 1):

For sorted frequencies, use a map then a slice. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    Input := []int{2, 2, 5, 7, 4, 4, 4, 7, 2}
    fmt.Println("Input:      ", Input)
    mFreq := make(map[int]int, len(Input))
    for _, n := range Input {
        mFreq[n]++
    }
    sFreq := make([][2]int, 0, len(mFreq))
    for n, f := range mFreq {
        sFreq = append(sFreq, [2]int{n, f})
    }
    sort.Slice(sFreq, func(i, j int) bool {
        if sFreq[i][1] <= sFreq[j][1] {
            if sFreq[i][1] < sFreq[j][1] {
                return false
            }
            if sFreq[i][0] >= sFreq[j][0] {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    },
    )
    Output := []int{2, 4, 7, 5}
    fmt.Println("Output:     ", Output)
    fmt.Println("Frequencies:", sFreq)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/8tiSksz3S76

Output:

```
Input:       [2 2 5 7 4 4 4 7 2]
Output:      [2 4 7 5]
Frequencies: [[2 3] [4 3] [7 2] [5 1]]
```